# Xcode: Frame capture a third-party app without project

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to use Xcode's Frame Capture tool and Shader profiler on a third-party app?

In particular, the app is my Unity game, which means I do have access to its source code, but not Xcode project because Unity doesn't generate Xcode project for macOS standalone build (it only generates them for iOS build).

So what options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was possible: but we need to setup a new project and edit the executable to be profiled.

> From a Metal template (create a brand new Metal project in Xcode), you can target to launch your own executable (Product —> Scheme —>  Edit Scheme —> Info —> Executable). Make sure that "GPU Frame Capture" (same menu Options tab) is set to Metal

via https://twitter.com/ayucebilgin/status/1075834617247068160